# Redirecting stderr in function

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

Is there any way to redirect in specific function stderr from previous command to a file? Here is the sample code:

```
#! /bin/bash

error_action () {
    echo "Failed! Check $ERR_LOG" 
    exit 1
}

apt-get install -y build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r) >/dev/null || error_action
```

Comment: you asking for redirect the error to a file?

Comment: Function should redirect stderr output from previous command to a specific file and then run echo "Failed! Check $ERR_LOG"

Comment: Dkid you consider using `logger`  (the command doing `syslog`)?

Answer (score 1):

The thing you're looking for is called "process substitution", and you can read about it in bash's man page in the "EXPANSION" section.

Any filehandle (including stdout and stderr) can be redirected to either a file or a pipe.  The notation of `<(command)` handles input redirection from a command, and `>(command)` handles output.  And as long as you've defined your shell function, that can be your command.  For example, try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

errout () {
  sed 's/^/ERROR> /'
}

stdout () {
  sed 's/^/stdout> /'
}

ls -l /bin/ls /nonexistent 2> >(errout) > >(stdout)
```

On my system, `ls` will show a line for `/bin/ls` that goes to stdout, and will show an error for `/nonexistent` which goes to stderr:

```
$ ./errtest
ERROR> ls: /nonexistent: No such file or directory
stdout> -r-xr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  32672 Nov  8  2012 /bin/ls
$
```

Be careful of the order in which you do your redirections.  Redirections are processed in the order they appear, left to right.

Answer (score 0):

(reedit to answer question)

If you want to capture the stderr output of the `apt-get` command and use it after you hae checked the exit status of the command, the best way is to capture the output in a file and then `cat` it out

```
apt-get ..... 2>$tmp_file || (echo "Failed! Check $ERR_LOG" | cat - $tmp_file)
```

The `cat` can be optionally redirected to stderr if required.

Comment: I ve tried - stderr output still appears on the screen.

Comment: Try this one echo "Failed! Check $ERR_LOG" 2>log_file it will redirect the error to file

Comment: Still the same thing(

Comment: Sorry - misunderstood question - you want to redirect the stderr or the get-apt command, not the error_action()

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
apt-get install -y build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r) 2>$ERR_LOG 1>/dev/null || error_action
```

This will put the command's stderr output in the error log file that you later print from the error method, and stdout to `dev/null` as in the original command.

Comment: It's working, but а little not so as I wanted - 2>$ERR_LOG should be in function somehow.

Answer (score -1):

Use this command to redirect the error to log_file

```
echo "Failed! Check $ERR_LOG" 2>log_file
```

Redirect the error to dev/null and print the output on the screen

```
apt-get install -y build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r) 2>/dev/null || error_action
```